# how to get gps coordinate using one coordinate and distance

Tags: math, gps, coordinate

[image]

For example , it assumes that the black rectangle is a square.

and The gps coordinates of the red circle , which is in the square is ***lat 126.993611 long 37.5727***

i want to know the yellow circle and blue circle coordinates displayed on the screen.

Units of length are all ***M(meter)***

please let me know best calculate formula!

Answer (score 0):

You can use geofence for this.
https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

or you write a method which calculates your distance by coordinates.
Then you can use a rise and this method to get the new location.